# Flickering when animating movement of elements in Windows Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requestanimationframe

#### I've animated `element.style.left` in Windows Chrome

When I use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the `element.style.left` of an absolute-positioned `<div>`, the animation does not appear smooth in Google Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

#### The leading edge of the animated element flickers and looks awful

The leading edge of the div seems to disappear / flicker while it's moving. When it moves in the other direction, the other edge disappears / flickers.

[image: Div has missing edge]

In Firefox and Microsoft Edge and on my mobile Chrome, the animation is smooth with no flickering.

#### Full code example to demonstrate the problem

I've written a simple demo that bounces a div from side to side and shows the problem.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('example')
var left = 20
var increment = 2

function animationStep(timestamp) {
  if (left < 20 || left > 200) {
    increment = -increment
  }
  left += increment
  element.style.left = (left + 'px')
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animationStep)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(animationStep)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    
    #example {
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 15px;
      top: 50px;
      padding: 6px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="example">Example</div>

  <script>
    // ...as below
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

#### Am I doing something wrong?

Does anyone know what is going on with Chrome on Windows 10? Is there something wrong with my code? If not, are there any good workrounds to stop the flickering? The only one I can think of is to place my div inside a bigger div with an invisible background. For various reasons, I don't want to use CSS animations.

Comment: A lot of factors can make this juddering happen, like how busy your machine is, if the browser is hardware accelerated, if your machine has dedicated graphics, is your machine in low-power/battery-saver mode, etc. Alternatively, don't use JS. Use CSS animations instead.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I've got a fast machine with a high-end graphics card and the system isn't loaded. The animation runs perfectly in Firefox and MS Edge. It never used to flicker in Chrome but now it flickers consistently. This is a cutdown example. The full thing is not amenable to CSS animations. :(

Comment: As a (poor) workaround, I've found that if I skip every other animation frame, the flickering stops.

Comment: That's pretty bad what they are doing with their Hardware Acceleration everywhere... At least the third bug I see linked to HWA in last three weeks... So disabling HardwareAcceleration will make it work seemlessly, but there might be workarounds, depending on what is your exact case. Here you made a good minimal repro, but I guess your case is more complicated. CSS transitions an WebAnimations still work correctly, so if you really just have linear anims like that, you can use these instead: 
https://jsfiddle.net/n763roqk/, but you'll probably need to tell us in your question.